# Global variable undefined

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I am struggling to understand the scopes in javascript

I am making a simple call to google drive api and I want to access the variable outside the function.

My code;

```
var newDate;
getLiveDate(lastFileId);
console.log(newDate);

function getLiveDate(fileId) {
    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': 'drive/v2/files/' + fileId,
        'method': 'GET',
        'params': {
            'fileId': fileId
        }
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
        newDate = resp.modifiedDate;
    });
}
```

In the console, newDate is undefined why is this?

Comment: Because the call `getLiveDate()` makes an asynchronous HTTP request (AJAX) and the variable isn't yet populated when you call `console.log()` Call it inside `request.execute()` and you'll see its value.

Comment: I think you have a sync problem, not a scope problem.  Move the log to within the request.execute after you set newDate... does it work?

Comment: Did you try to place an `alert("test")` inside your request.execute callback function? Just to be sure your callback function gets called.

Comment: *"I am struggling to understand the scopes in javascript"* The good news here is that it's not a scope thing at all. :-) The scope part of your code is just fine (other than that global variables should be avoided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those requests to google's API are *async* calls - so the next piece of code is executed while that function is still processing. The correct way to do this is to use callbacks rather than globals:

```
function getLiveDate(fileId, callback) {
    ...
    request.execute(function(resp) {
        callback(resp);
    });
}
```

And call this

```
getLiveDate(lastFileId, function(resp) {
    console.log(resp); //your data
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The API call is asynchronous. Your `console.log()` executes before a response has been received from the API.

The function passed to `execute()` is the callback and so you should move any logic that depends on the API response to there.

```
request.execute(function(resp) {
    newDate = resp.modifiedDate;

    // this is the callback, do your logic that processes the response here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because, `request.execute` is an asynchronous function. Even before

```
newDate = resp.modifiedDate;
```

is executed,

```
console.log(newDate);
```

is executed. So, your best bet would be to print it in the callback function, like this

```
request.execute(function(resp) {
    newDate = resp.modifiedDate;
    console.log(newDate);
});
```